# Vim, find the n'th occurence of a word

Tags: linux, vim

I tried using the following syntax, in Vim to find the n'th occurence of a word(i would like to replace that word with another one)

```
:6:myWord
```

and I would like to replace it with newWord

I do not understand what I am getting wrong, can anybody help me?

Comment: (1) Open the file with `vim`, (2) type `6/myWord`, then (3) press Enter. In the visual mode, entering a number followed by a command executes that command that number of times. So this executes `/myWord` 6 times, which finds the 6th occurrence of `myWord`.

Answer (score 1):

```
s/\%(\(myWord\).\{-}\)\{6}\zs\1/newWord/
           ^             ^             ^
            Pattern       Occurrence    Replace pattern
```

It will replace the 6th occurrence of a myWord to newWord.

Comment: cool!! (+1) but:  it replaces the 7th oco in the same line.  `:1s/\v%((myWord)\_.{-}){5}\zs\1/newWord/ `

Answer (score 1):

**Gnu-sed** This is not an answer to the question: it is just an alternative way of changing the n'th occurence. For a proper answer see @sureshkumar's answer and @lurker's comment.

```
sed -z -i.bak s/myWord/newWord/6  file
```

where:

```
-i.bak    infile editing (creating file.bak as a bakup)
-z        null separeted registers (all file = one register) (gnu sed)
/6        6'th occurence
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully. The question in in vim editor we have to replace not in command line.

Comment: @sureshkumar,  it was not meant to be a proper answer...  (I added a disclaimer aout it). Of course we can: `:%!sed -z  s/myWord/newWord/6`

Comment: @sureshkumar: tahnk you. Again you are right.  Added a note -- just in gnu sed.

Comment: Thank you @JJoao, I was looking for a solution to do the replace using vim, this is how I got to this page. Your answer is much better. People using vim are most probably also comfortable with the command line. I had to replace the 5th occurance of a separator and remove it on each line. So I this without the -z. Works perfectly!